# Combine 2 rows of a table by selecting greatest values of two differing fields between the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in a similar format to this:

```
  COMPANY   | DESCRIPTION |   CODE_A   |   CODE_B
-----------------------------------------------------
ABC         | XYZ         | 123        |  0
ABC         | XYZ         | 0          |  987
DEF         | UVW         | 0          |  654
GHI         | RST         | 0          |  321
GHI         | RST         | 456        |  0
```

I need to instead have all the distinct companies as single rows, where the greatest value for `CODE_A` and `CODE_B` for each company is taken, and the value for `DESCRIPTION` remains as is for all companies.

The resulting table would look like this:

```
  COMPANY   | DESCRIPTION |   CODE_A   |   CODE_B
-----------------------------------------------------
ABC         | XYZ         | 123        |  987
DEF         | UVW         | 0          |  654
GHI         | RST         | 456        |  321
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple max() and group by

```
select code, description, max(code_a), max(code_b)
from MyTable
group by code, description
```

Answer (score 0):

By using Window function

```
SELECT DISTINCT COMPANY, 
        [description],
        max(CODE_A) OVER(PARTITION by COMPANY,[description] Order by COMPANY) AS CODE_A,
        max(CODE_B) OVER(PARTITION by COMPANY,[description]  Order by description) AS CODE_B
from cte
```